# Extract number before a specific character in a string

Tags: sas, sas-macro

[image]

Question:
In the column WR_Name how do i extract the number before the first percentage in SAS and add the results in a new column name called readings?

Comment: Try looking into the `INDEX` function, which will help you find the position of the first percentage character

Comment: Can you post your code, and not pictures of your code? It is far easier to help you if we can copy/paste code instead of retyping.

Answer (score 0):

`readings = scan(scan(WR_NAME, 1 '%'), -1);`

`scan("one two tree four", 2)` will return the second word in the string: "two"

`scan` accepts a third parameter to slit your string by something else than spaces, in this case a percentage sign.

If the second parameter of `scan` is negative, it starts from the end instead of the beginning.